# OBIEE 11g Construct Date From Strings

Tags: oracle, date, oracle11g, business-intelligence, obiee

I'm having trouble working with presentation variables and dates:
My prompt assigns a range of dates to a variable in this format *YYYY-MM,YYYY-MM*.

I need the number of months running between those two.
I tried to SUBSTRING each part of the variable, CONCATENATE and CAST as DATE, but I get errors upon errors.

For instance, I used to SUBSTRING and CAST as INTEGER the month part of the variable:

```
cast(SUBSTRING('@{range}{2018-01,2018-10}' FROM 14 FOR 2) as integer)
```

Can anybody help me out here?

Comment: Please give an [MCVE] including the code you have tried and the error messages they gave.

Comment: Also: 2018-01 is not a date.